# React.Fragment component is not rendering within other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The React.Fragment(in the below code `FragmenttedComp`) is not rendering in the `ChildComponent`

Here is my code,

```
 export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    .
    .
    .
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const prop = this.props.prop;
        const desc = <FragmenttedComponent inputText={prop.desc} />;

        let newProp = {};
        newProp.desc = desc;

        return  (
            <ChildComponent
                prop={newProp}
            />);
    }
 }
```

`FragmenttedComponent` would be something like the below,

```
<em>{desc}</em>
```

The `FragmenttedComponent` when passed to the `ChildComponent` as the property, it is not being rendered inside the `InnerComponent`.

```
 export class ChildComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    .
    .
    .
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const prop = this.props.prop;
        return  (
            <InnerComponent
                label={prop.desc}
            />);
    }
 }
```

`InnerComponent` does something like the below with the label,

```
InnerComponent.prototype.render = function () {
    var _a = this.props, label = _a.label;
    var labelElement = label ? (React.createElement("div", { id: "label" }, label)) : null;
   
    return (React.createElement("div", { className: className },
        React.createElement("span", { }, labelElement)));
};
```

The above code works if the `FragmenttedComponent` is defined in the `ChildComponent` instead of the `ParentComponent`.

```
export class ChildComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    .
    .
    .
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const prop = this.props.prop;
        const desc = <FragmenttedComponent inputText={prop.desc} />;
        return  (
            <InnerComponent
                label={desc}
            />);
    }
 }
```

Can't I pass the `FragmenttedComponent` JSX element from one component to the other?

Is there a way to fix this, without moving the `FragmenttedComponent` from the `ParentComponent` to the `ChildComponent`?

Comment: Since InnerComponent renders FragmentComponent, could you please share InnerComponent code?

Comment: @SerhiiBilyk added the InnerComponent code snippet